# Settings get global mobile_data always returns 0

Tags: root-access, mobile-data, scripts

On a rooted mediatek 6580 phone running Android 5.1.1, if data is enabled using `svc data enable` or even pulling down the notification bar, the command `settings get global mobile_data` shows an output of `0` instead of `1`. As a result if running from a script, such like;

```
while true; do
sleep 10
if [ `settings get global mobile_data` == "0" ]; then
svc data enable
else
svc data disable
fi
done
```

This script turns on data successfully, but couldn't turn data off after 10 seconds, since `settings get global mobile_data` always returns 0. Where as, I did the same with **wifi** as in replaced mobile_data with wifi and `svc wifi enable/disable` Wifi seemed to do the job as expected. Turned on after 10 seconds, and after 10 seconds turned itself off and repeat. I wonder why it isn't the same with mobile data. Manually running `svc data disable` turns off data, but running from a script seems to be a problem in this case.

Comment: Try `settings get global mobile_data${i}` where `i` is 1 to 9.

Comment: Unfortunately all of them returns 0 from 1-9 even if data is on

Comment: Save all settings to a text file before and after switching Mobile Data on or off. Take a diff of both files to see what keys/values changed.